# Display an inline pane in Monaco

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using a literate code tool to generate a nice HTML representation of the source code of a project.
I'd like to use Monaco to show all of the code and provide smart features like "go to definition", folding, etc., but I need to include the inline literate code comments. "Go to definition" and "Find all references" show their results inline. Is it possible to show a similar pane with custom content? I'd rather not create a separate (read-only) editor for every code block, unless that can be done without too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to not be possible right now. I looked into it more, downloading the code for vscode and editing it a bit. The terminology used in the code for inline widgets is "zone widget" or "peek view widget." I found a tracking issue for allowing custom zone widgets: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3220, in which people ask for a similar feature.

> I've been trying to find a way to render markdown and diagrams inline with the code. We have a lot of mathematical notations and flowcharts that should ideally be shown right in the comments, instead of just being linked.

Currently, the issue is still open, so it is not possible with current APIs.